# AJAX Add To Cart

Tags: cart

Wondering what modules are out there for an AJAX add to cart / my cart feature.  From a quick google search, I'm not in love with the UI of most of the extensions that I'm finding.

The UI / functionality that I'm interested actually seems super simple.  Maybe I'm not thinking of some features, but basically it's simply:

- Take the My Cart page and pop it in a modal when they click Add To Cart
- But remove the coupon / shipping options b/c that would be overkill.

I like how Gilt does it.

[image: Gilt My Cart]

Any good modules out there that I'm missing?  If not I may just build this - it seems like all I need to do is re-use the block on the My Cart page, and just pop it inside of a modal, and call it a day.

Comment: I don't know any module, but why not just fire an ajax request to add the product and writing a observer which removes all the unneeded blocks?

Comment: Well, probably won't need an observer because I'll just be able to control the layout for the modal that I launch.  But ya it seems really simple to implement.

Comment: Have a look at this extension : **http://www.magento-connect.org/catalog-products-pop-up-with-ajax-cart-magento-extensions.html**

and this **http://excellencetechnologies.co.in/Telephonia/blog/ajax-based-product-add-to-cart-from-category-page/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used a few:

**Aheadworks Ajax Cart Pro:**

http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/ajax-cart-pro.html

Which works really well. You can see it in action on http://shop.harpersbazaar.com

**Amasty Ajax Cart:**

http://amasty.com/ajax-shopping-cart.html

Works pretty well, too. Big upside on this one is the javascript is entirely Prototype-based. No duplicated jQuery dependency to worry about.

But - don't be afraid to roll your own! It's not so difficult:

- The controller action needs to rewrite `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, specifically the `addAction` -- better yet, use a `postdispatch` event observer.
- The UI modal components for the success message are always on the page, so your ajax callback really only needs a `true` or `false` to display the appropriate message.
- Don't forget to provide support for related products (which can be added in tandem) and for various product types: simple, configurable, bundle. Don't forget grouped or downloadable, either. Everyone forget those :(

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Phil!  So I guess there aren't any on the market that do it how Gilt does it?

Answer (score 0):

I have used N19 Advanced Ajax Cart its contain awesome features in this cart, so go with this 
Ajax Cart Extension I wish u will enjoy and fullfill your requirements. It also contain many options like Drag and Drop and Add to wish list , empty cart from side bar,Ajax Bundle Product
Ajax quantity update,Configure Product,Unique and creative loaders

You can visit : http://shop.syncwebagency.com
                http://shop.syncwebagency.com/n19-ajax-cart-advanced.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have a [Magento Ajax Extension](http://www.magebuzz.com/ajax-cart.html)

[image]

- It allows the buyers to select product options in a responsive popup
- Instantly adds products to cart without reloading pages
- Permits admin to turn on/ off confirmation popup
- Adds products from wishlist
- Supports multiple stores
- Immediately updates cart information in sidebar and header
- Enables/disables Ajax cart functions
- Adds products from comparison page
- Supports a variety of product types, customizes success message